# fullcalendar not connecting with gcal -why?

Tags: cordova, fullcalendar, gcal

I have the calendar running well but it will not connect to the public test Google Calendar I have made. I have been through all the steps twice to make sure I didnt miss anything. I know its connecting properly since when I change the API key it throws an error. In my google developers dash I can see requests being made for data but they dont show in the actual Fullcalendar. There are no errors in the inspector console. Can anyone who has connected FullCalender to gcal shed some light on what I am missing? Here is the complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!--
        Customize this policy to fit your own app's needs. For more guidance, see:
            https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#content-security-policy
        Some notes:
            * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
            * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
            * Disables use of inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
                * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap: ws: https://ssl.gstatic.com;style-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'self' data: blob:;script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="fullcalendar.css"/>
        <script src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="fullcalendar.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="gcal.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        googleCalendarApiKey: 'AIzaSyAq_BYJLX78-t4Xn6g4wZouE0D1_I5HJlM',
        events: {
            googleCalendarId: 'pcr0c6flf63fc80in0eua7amd8@group.calendar.google.com',
            className: 'gcal-event' // an option!
        }
    });
});

</script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="calendar"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

<!--        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>
-->
```

Comment: "In my google developers dash I can see requests being made for data but they dont show in the actual Fullcalendar"...what do those requests return? Is there some valid data in them which falls within the dates being displayed in the fullCalendar at that moment? You can look inside each request and see the Response body and also the HTTP response code.

Comment: No requests returned. All I can see is the activity that it is connecting. I do have an event from yesterday, the 18th, that just says test which should be showing up. It is not. Perhaps I dont know how to look for what youre suggesting?

Comment: Look in the Network tab in your browser's developer tools. You should see an ajax request going to Google, I think, probably the URL starts `event?callback`.... Click on that. Details of the request will appear on the right. Click the "response" tab. In that you should see some JSON containing the event data. Is what you see? If not, what do you see instead? Also what is the response status of that request? Is it 200 OK, or something else?

Comment: Indeed it is a 200. jquery.min.js:4 is the initiator, size is 353b, time is 232ms. Other details:

// API callback jQuery321015338189860786233_1516558960093({kind: "calendar#events", etag: ""p33sfrmlosvhdg0g"", summary: "Kb Test Cal",…} );
accessRole
:
"freeBusyReader"
defaultReminders
:
[]
etag
:
""p33sfrmlosvhdg0g""
items
:
[]
kind
:
"calendar#events"
nextSyncToken
:
"CPj92rjn4tgCEAAYCg=="
summary
:
"Kb Test Cal"
timeZone
:
"America/New_York"
updated
:
"2018-01-19T00:50:21.963Z"

Comment: I made http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/123/ to connect to your calendar. I get this back: `// API callback
jQuery32102864230182558851_1516559660491({
 "kind": "calendar#events",
 "etag": "\"p33sfrmlosvhdg0g\"",
 "summary": "Kb Test Cal",
 "updated": "2018-01-19T00:50:21.963Z",
 "timeZone": "America/New_York",
 "accessRole": "freeBusyReader",
 "defaultReminders": [],
 "nextSyncToken": "CPj92rjn4tgCEAAYCg==",
 "items": []
}
);`  Also I loaded https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=pcr0c6flf63fc80in0eua7amd8%40group.calendar.google.com&ctz=Europe%2FLondon in my browser

Comment: Looking at both of those, it connects fine, but it seems like you simply have no events in your Google calendar. I'm sure it'll work fine once you actually populate the calendar.

Comment: Thats very odd because looking at calendar view I can see the test I put on the calendar on the 18th.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. I can't see it. Are you certain you added the event to the correct calendar? Are you certain the calendar is set public in in the correct way? Have I got the correct URL (perhaps you can confirm to me the public URL for the calendar by looking in its settings?). Try looking at the public calendar page (i.e the URL I linked to above, if that's correct) while not logged into your google account and see if you can see it then.

Comment: P.S. Here's an existing public calendar which was created to work with a site I built: https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=icseb8he7tp9s3pmq5lu8pkn0c%40group.calendar.google.com&ctz=Europe%2FLondon with events clearly visible in it, and here's a JSFiddle showing fullCalendar linking to the calendar and displaying events in exactly the way you're doing: http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/163/ So it's clearly possible for it to work if the calendar is configured properly and the events are in the right calendar. I can't see your actual google account setup to help with that, unfortunately.

Comment: Indeed. Added another one yesterday. Is there a way I can share a screen shot here? I dont see it in your fiddle but in your second link for the browser I do see it.

Comment: This is silly. So the solution this whole time was to go into EACH EVENT separately and mark it is public. Even though the calendar is public, each event has to be marked as such ALSO. Google buries this in their documentation. Thank you very much for your help on this.

Comment: No problem. Worth pointing out that as far as I know, "Public" is normally the default value for a new event. Have you changed it in your settings somehow?